# Communicate with several ports on a server using multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, tcp

I apologize for the multiple questions but I am having a hard time finding information on exactly what I am trying to do here.

**Background:**

I am working on a project that involves communicating with several server ports simultaneously that needs to somewhat scale. Some background on the project is I have a web application for users to pass commands to a console application. This console application will then send those commands to a specific port on a preexisting server through a tcp client.

My specific questions regard the console application communicating with the preexisting server.

**My idea:**

So my idea is to use a producer-many consumers thread scheme. I will need to be able to communicate with up to 300 different ports simultaneously and constantly through TCP connections. This console application will run as a windows service or something along those lines.
[image]

**Question 1:**

I am thinking of using a **ConcurrentDictionary<string,ConcurrentQueue>()** to track a queue of commands for every specific thread. Is there a better way to do this? I ask because I assume every thread would need access to the entire Dictionary of commands correct? Maybe this is a good approach but I have never done something like this.

**Question 2:**

Does spawning a single thread for each port I need to send commands to on the server make sense? The only reason I am thinking of doing this is because I will need to keep a TCP connection open for a very long time. The user can choose when to shut down the tool/connection. The only requirement really is this needs to be communicating for days at a time. The MOST I will reach is about 300 threads using this approach.

**Question 3:**

Obviously using an asynchronous approach is going to be necessary for this to scale well. Can anyone point me to some GOOD not out dated resources of the PROPER way to implement something like this asynchronously. I am willing to even pay for a book / online course if you have a good recommendation.  The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) are not very helpful because they do a scheme of 1 send and 1 read and then close the tcp connection.

Comment: I feel that SignalR should be mentioned here. Why or why not are you using SignalR? Have you seen this Command and Control sample from David Fowler? https://github.com/davidfowl/CommandAndControl

Comment: @thewallrus Thanks for the reply. For the SignalR example you just linked, its linking to a SignalRHub where I am hooking into a preexisting 3rd party box/server with ports. I thought about using SignalR but is this example going to transfer well for something that doesn't use a signalR hub?

Comment: Just an additional note, the web server does support web sockets, I know SignalR client can use sockets to communicate. Can I communicate via web sockets from JS using SignalR?

Comment: Is the source of commands here a single web application, or is this acting as a server for multiple client web applications? If it's a single web application (so a user can't reasonably enter more than a few commands per second) it's probably overkill, but it might make more sense if there may be on the order of dozens of client web apps feeding it commands.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be working with threads, 300 is far too many. You should move to a fully `async` model where there will be a `Task` for each port which waits for messages to send, you use `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable` for this. So you probably want something like a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, BlockingCollection>()` to manage the list of ports. To shut them down you call `BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding`.

Comment: Right now it will be coming from one web app, but multiple clients / computers will be using the same web app. I do like the idea of communicating via the client UI (Javascript / SignalR) using websockets instead of having a totally separate console application to pull commands. @JerryCoffin.

Comment: @Charlieface I actually have to send a "Keep Alive" command (specific sequence of character bits) to each port every 10 seconds as well. So is 300 tools all performing commands every 10 seconds going to be to much for a single thread to handle even with Async?

Comment: With 300 tools and 10 seconds per keepalive, you only need to send 30 keepalive messages per second. That's well within the capabilities of a single thread (and presumably, you only need to send keepalives to tools that aren't receiving any other messages in that 10 seconds, reducing the load further).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you so much for the insight Jerry. Do you think perhaps having the individual clients (in the UI with SignalR and web sockets) would be a better way to communicate everything? Then realistically I can just have a JS function that executes my command via the socket every 10 seconds and I have everything I need to map to the server port for the tool in the UI. I am assuming SignalR can be used in JS to communicate with server ports/sockets the way I am thinking. I think doing it this way would really simplify things since I wont even need to worry about passing commands along.

Comment: @Selthien: At least right off, that sounds like a simpler, cleaner design, yes (with the proviso that I don't know JS particularly well, and barely know SignalR at all, beyond kind of a general awareness of the sorts of things it does).

Comment: That's not how async works normally. It's based around a threadpool, where the .NET Runtime manages a bunch of threads (usually not more than the necessary to service pending tasks). You simply do `await stream.Write` and the threadpool handles the hand-off and continuation of the rest of the function (you may also need `ConfigureAwait(false)` if running in a UI or ASP.Net Classic context). In terms of keep-alives: 30 keep-alives is indeed not much.

Comment: And the whole point of using `async` is that the thread doesn't wait for a response before moving onto the next task, it simply registers a continuation so that when the response comes through it can pick up the rest of the function. It's likely to be *more* efficient than separate threads, not less, when used in a high-load environment